# Wierd character for "Command not found" error in Bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am trying to debug a script I am writing, but the "command" that Bash can't find is just a weird character.

Section of script throwing error. Specifically, it is the 'echo' line:

[image: Section of script throwing error. Specifically it is the 'echo' line]

The error in question:

[image: The error in question]

error, but in xterm as opposed to URXVT:

[image: Same error, but in xterm as opposed to URXVT]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, show the problematic line as piped to `xxd`. There seems to be a weird character at the beginning of the line, perhaps a part of a MSWin line terminator.

Comment: @choroba I went to open the file again to add the xxd command and noticed that there was a period between the two tabs. That's what did it.

Comment: @TheMohawkNinja is this now closed and understood? It would be good to create a solution so that others can see what you did.

Answer (score -1):

Had a period between two of my tabs. Was really hard  to see due to transparency.